# Changing Element Value in Existing XML File Using DOM

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to find examples of how to change an existing xml files Element Value.

Using the following xml example:

```
<book>
  <title>My Book</title>
  <author>John Smith</author>
</book>
```

If I wanted to replace the author element value 'John Smith' with 'Jim Johnson' in a Python script using DOM, how would I go about doing so? I've tried to look for examples on this, but have failed in doing so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Rylic

Answer (score 5):

Presuming

```
s = '''
<book>
  <title>My Book</title>
  <author>John Smith</author>
</book>'''
```

DOM would look like:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

dom = minidom.parseString(s) # or parse(filename_or_file)
for author in dom.getElementsByTagName('author'):
    author.childNodes = [dom.createTextNode("Jane Smith")]
```

But I'd encourage you to look into ElementTree, it makes working with XML a breeze:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

et = ElementTree.fromstring(s) # or parse(filename_or_file)
for author in et.findall('author'):
    author.text = "Jane Smith"
```

Comment: IThanks for your help. I used ElementTree as you suggested, and it works fine. I am able to write to the xml file with the change that was needed. I did notice that when the file is written to, a lock is put on the file. I am presuming that the file is still open for writting. Is there a close method to unlock the file after writting to it with ElementTree?

Comment: @rylic38 How are you handling writing the file? Can you paste a code sample up on http://pastie.org/?

Comment: pastie.org is unfortunetly not accessable at work. I'll try to add it here:

import os
import xml

from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
path = "C:\\temp\\books.xml"
tree = et.parse(path)
for author in tree.findall('author'): 
 author.text = "Jane Doe"
 tree.write(path)

When I run this line by line at the command line, the xml file is written to, but is locked. If I exit python, the file is released, and I can then see the change.

Comment: The format came out unreadable, I seperated each line with "***". I hope that makes it more readable.

import os ***
import xml ***

from xml.etree import ElementTree as et***
path = "C:\\temp\\books.xml"***
tree = et.parse(path)***
for author in tree.findall('author'): ***
 author.text = "Jane Doe" ***
 tree.write(path) ***